# Wrong usage of the [epm] tag

Tags: discussion, tags, retag-request

[35 questions are tagged `epm`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bepm%5D+is%3Aquestion), whose Usage guide is:

> A piece of software issued by SAP frequently used as an Add-On to Excel. It allows users, typically in the financial sector, to interact with databases from an Excel interface. Also frequently referred to as "BPC".

However, the tag `epm` is used mainly by other topics:

- [Enterprise Performance Management](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enterprise_performance_management)

  - SAP, 5
  - Oracle/Hyperion/ESSBase, 9
- Enhanced Protection Mode (Internet Explorer), 8
- EPM Linux package manager, 2
- [Enterprise project management](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enterprise_project_management) (Microsoft Project/PSI), 8
- Others, 3

There are only five questions for [SAP EPM](https://wiki.scn.sap.com/wiki/display/CPM/EPM+WIKI+Home) Add-In.

How can this be resolved?

Comment: All of this is a big yikes to me - are *any* of these things on-topic for Stack Overflow?

Comment: @Makoto Without looking some of them could be.  Making your website work even if the browser is locked down or configuring your build system to create what a package system wants would be on topic.

Comment: TLT strikes again, when will we learn?

Comment: Resolve it by removing the tag from all but the 5 questions were it applies. Then rename the tag to something else that won't be confused, like `[sap-epm]`.

Comment: I'll leave the cleanup to the community, but ping me when it's done; I can take care of the rename bit when the cleanup is done

Comment: @zoe-stands-with-ukraine For now, I have re-tagged the 5 questions as `[sap-epm]`. Is it possible to just move the tag info from `[epm]` to `[sap-epm]`? (I can't do it myself, need 20k points, and right now the edit queue is full) - NB: I found it easier to just re-tag SAP EPM questions, for the rest I don't want to take the "responsibility", I prefer sticking to the "SAP world".

Comment: The thing about renaming is that it relies on the merger system, which also brings over tag wikis, including correct revision attribution. I'll just move it manually this time though, but that was _the_ reason to leave sap questions and retag everything else. All good though, there's no point in undoing it now

Comment: @pjs Three Letter Tag.